# Reactjs - handleChange with varying number of arguments

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple data table that is editable.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if my `handleChange` function can take in a varying number of arguments?

For example, is there a way I can do something like this and be able to get the value from my `TextInput`?

```
<TextInput
          name={this.props.headers[i-1].id}
          onChange={(event) => this.onInputChange(row.id, this.props.headers[i-1].id, event)}
          disabled={(this.isBeingEdited(row.id) === false)}
          value={row[rowKeys[i]]}
/>
```

where my `TextInput`'s `handleChange` looks like this:

```
handleChange = event => {
    var value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ value: value }, () => this.checkForErrors());
    this.props.onChange(this.props.name, value);
}
```

Right now, it's just giving me the `this.props.name` and `value` but I'd also like the `row.id`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with? `this.props.onChange(id, this.props.name, value);`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I want to try to avoid editing `TextInput` if possible because it's a generic component used by other components :-(

Comment: Even, can't you add props? Then, no way to do.